# Update column with sort number based on another column value

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

Say I have a two column table.  The first column 'value' is filled with random numbers.  The second column 'sort' is empty.  How can I update 'sort' with integers in order, the smallest integer being assigned to the largest value in the column 'value'

So starting with:

```
Value | Sort
76    | 0
82    | 0
7     | 0
14    | 0
```

the result would be:

```
Value | Sort
76    | 2
82    | 1
7     | 4
14    | 3
```

Comment: Always tag the DBMS you're using (SQL Server, MySQL..etc)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming what SQL you are using you could use a row_number() function to get the rows that would be ordered in the way you want.

Using `OVER` Clause:

```
update table1
set sort = t.rnum 
from (select table1.value, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value desc) as rnum from table1) t
```

Comment: @MiloLaMar Yes, if he can provide which server he is using I can change my code accordingly.

Comment: It is oracle.  I was just thinking it might be easiest to do something like "big number" - Value = sort number.

Comment: @AaronDietz I will update my answer using `Over` clause. Since he is using Oracle

Comment: Does the first version work without an inline view, i.e. isn't `rownum` set _before_ the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic &AaronDietz Thanks for pointing that out. I was a bit confused at first on what server he is using. I have removed my first option.

Comment: This query made all sort columns as "1". I changed it as: "update table1
set sort = t.rnum 
from (select table1.value, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value desc) as rnum from table1) t
WHERE t.value = table1.value" Then it worked as I expected